# PHP syntax error: Unexpected ']'

Tags: php, sql, iis, syntax, syntax-error

I'm running PHP on a Windows 8.1 server with IIS. I have a PHP script, and have managed to turn displaying errors on. I found an error on this line.

`$hr06status = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT status FROM hours WHERE hour = 6"))['status'];`

The exact error is `on line 14 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: Try `$hr06status = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT status FROM hours WHERE hour = 6")); $hr06status = $hr06status['status'];`

Comment: Thanks! This fixes the problem, and it appears on the next line. (I have this code 18 times with different numbers.)

Comment: Or try `mysqli_fetch_object(...)->status`

Comment: Array dereferencing was only introduced in 5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You trying to do [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) which is only available in PHP 5.4 or later. You are probably running a version older than that so that line of code won't work.

The code in the comment above is the correct way to write it for your version of PHP.

Comment: Pre PHP 5.4: `Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable: an E_NOTICE-level error message will be issued, and the result will be NULL.` - manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-89

Comment: I will update instead of changing my code. When was PHP 5.4 released? My server has only been running for about 2 weeks.

Comment: It was released in March 2012

Comment: I was using 5.3 for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

Indexing on the return value of a function is something PHP added only recently. As Dave Chen says in the comment, you need an interim variable that you can then later index.